# Javascript one innerHTML not working, other works in code

Tags: javascript, html

My code currently is

```
var seltrack = document.getElementById('seltrack').innerHTML;
var selmodel = document.getElementById('selmodel').innerHTML;
```

and then later on in a loop I have:

```
selmodel = "Weight";
seltrack = "Best";
```

The HTML code is in a separate document with an appropriate link to the js script:

```
<p id='seltrack' style='display:inline;color:black;'></p>
<p id='selmodel' style='display:inline;color:black;'></p>
```

So for me, `seltrack` sets just fine, however, `selmodel` doesn't change. I tried checking what `selmodel` was after each iteration and it seemed to change the `innerHTML` properly, however it didn't show up on the actual webpage. I've tried looking for solutions but none of them seem to work. I can give extra information if this wasn't sufficient. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store a reference to an element's `innerHTML` property and then set that property via the reference. Neither of your examples should work:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML; // foo is a string
foo = "foo"; // document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML hasn't changed

console.log(foo);
console.log(document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="foo">Test</div>
```

You should instead store references to the Elements:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo'); // foo is an Element
foo.innerHTML = "foo";

console.log(foo.innerHTML);
console.log(document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="foo">Test</div>
```